# How to show on screen the cursor position on an android tablet or smartphone?

Tags: android

I would like to be able to show on the screen something like the mouse cursor on PC's. Does anyone know how to do it with an app or by modifying the options on the device?

Comment: Can you give any more information? Many Android tablets will provide a mouse cursor system-wide if you connect a Bluetooth mouse. Or do you mean something different, using either the touch controls or D-pad/trackball somehow?

Answer (score 11):

On Android 4.0, go to Settings > Developer Options > Pointer Location and toggle that on. This is very handy for presentations.

I am not aware of a solution for this on previous versions of Android.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the setting is in `Developer Options` as in @CommonsWare's answer. On `Jelly Bean`, the location of it started being [even trickier](http://www.ninjaromeo.com/enable-usb-debugging-developer-options-jelly-bean/).